# Unclear how expected value is arrived at in chi squared test calculation

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, independence, hypothesis-testing

Here is a question I'm doing to study for my introductory statistics final exam coming up in a few weeks. Specifically, I'm attempting part (c) here:

> A factory manufactures widgets. To successfully manufacture widgets, two machines must both be working. The production supervisor has noticed that in a $28$ day period, machine A was broken on $5$ days, and machine B was broken on $8$ days. Assuming that the chance of a machine to be broken on a given day is independent of its chance to be broken on any day.
>
> (a) Calculate a $95$% confidence interval for the percentage of days that machine A is broken.
>
> (b) Is there evidence in the data collected that machine B is less reliable than machine A? What additional assumptions are you making, if any?
>
> (c) The production supervisor's intuition suggests that the machines break down together more than should be expected. Over a $60$ day period, she observes that there are $14$ days when only machine A breaks down, $13$ days when only machine B breaks down, and $2$ days when both break down. Does this data support her intuition?

Here's the beginning of the model solutions provided:

[Picture of beginning of solution to part (c).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ4Tk.png)

However, it's unclear how they come up with the numbers $33$, $12$, $11$, and $2$ for expected values. It seems like they're pulling those numbers out of thin air. How do I get them?

I understand that the observed values are $31$, $14$, $13$, and $2$, but I don't understand why the expected values are $33$, $12$, $11$, and $2$. For instance, why can't they be e.g. $32$, $13$, $12$, and $3$ instead?

For reference, here are the complete solutions, where the solution to (c) starts on page 3: https://ams005-winter16-02.courses.soe.ucsc.edu/system/files/attachments/practice_final_1_solutions.pdf

Comment: In a two-way table: (Expected count) = (Row Count)(Column Count)/(Grand Total).

Comment: @SeanRoberson I understand that, I just don't understand the particular choice of numbers for the expected values.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? What don't you understand about "the particular choice of numbers for the expected values?" It's just following the computation - or is it something more?

Comment: How would you arrive at the numbers $33$, $12$, $11$, and $4$ given the problem statement for (c), for the expected values? It is not at all obvious. It's clear from the problem statement that the observed values are $31$, $14$, $13$, and $2$. But it seems like $33$, $12$, $11$, and $4$ are pulled out of thin air.

Comment: It's the maximum likelihood estimate assuming independence. Some more details here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-443-statistics-for-applications-fall-2006/3d1454c4ec106c4be8fd57df9acb559b_lecture13.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing magical here. Let $E_{ij}$ be the expected count in cell $(i, j)$ (that is, row $i$, column $j$). Let $x_{ij}$ be the actual count in $(i, j)$. For any row $i$, the row count is

$$S_{i, \cdot} = \sum_{k = 1}^n X_{ik}$$

and similar for the column count. Then

$$E_{ij} = \frac{S_{i, \cdot} S_{\cdot, j}}{\sum_{i, \ j} X_{ij}} $$

is the expected count in cell $(i, j).$ That is, as I said in my comment, The product of the row and column counts divided by the grand total.

Let's do the counts for your specific example.

$$\begin{align*}
E_{11} &= \frac{45 \cdot 44}{60} = 33 \\
E_{12} &= \frac{45 \cdot 16}{60} = 12 \\
E_{21} &= \frac{15 \cdot 44}{60} = 11 \\
E_{22} &= \frac{15 \cdot 16}{60} = 4
\end{align*}$$

I'm hoping this answers your question because I am not sure what else you would be looking for. The short version: just do the computations.